# Incompatible pointer type pointer to array and double pointer to array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, incompatibletypeerror, pointer-to-pointer

So i am new to programming and i have this program that i have to write, it has an array of integers and i have to pass it to a function with a pointer and then with a double pointer.
After i wrote the code i had this error that i couldn't find a solution to. The error is :

> initialization of 'int **' from incompatible pointer type 'int *'
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-type]

The code that i wrote is this:

```
int main(){
    int i;
    int arr[]={3,-15,19,0,-984};
    int *p=arr;
    funzione(p,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));      //The first function
    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++)  //print of the single pointer (p)
        printf("%d\n",p[i]);
    int **g=p;                                   //the error results to be coming from p in this row
    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++)  //print of the double pointer (g)
        printf("%d\n",g[i]);
    funzione2(g,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));     //The second function
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can i remove this error.

Comment: "how can i remove this error." Don't try to assign a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `int *`. What are you *trying* to do here? You can't just convert pointers like that and expect everything to work. `funzione2` would be expecting the first argument to point to one or more `int *`, not to just be a cast pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `p` has the type `int *` while the initialized variable `g` has the type `int **`.

```
int **g=p;                                   //the error results to be
```

These pointer types are not compatible and there is no implicit conversion from one pointer type to another.

You need to write

```
int **g = &p;
for(i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++)  //print of the double pointer (g)
    printf("%d\n",( *g )[i]);
```

Pay attention to that the for loop can look the same way if you will declare the pointer `g` also the following way

```
int ( *g )[5] = &arr;
for(i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++)  //print of the double pointer (g)
    printf("%d\n",( *g )[i]);
```

Also the expression `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` has the unsigned integer type `size_t`. So it would be better to declare the variable `i` also as having the unsigned type `size_t` instead of the signed type `int`.

```
size_t i;
```

Though it is even much better to declare the variable `i` in the minimal scope where it is used as for example

```
for( size_t i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++)  //print of the double pointer (g)
    printf("%d\n",( *g )[i]);
```

And this called function

```
funzione2(g,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));     //The first function
```

is not the first function as it is written in the comment.:)

Answer (score 0):

### **Note: This is not a rigorous answer but it is enough for you to continue and solve your compiler issue.**

See, `p` has type `int*` while `g` is of type `int**`. They are incompatible as the error clearly states.
`p` is a pointer to int while `g` is a point to a pointer to `int`.
If you do `int **g=&p;` the compiler will stop complaining because the types now match.

The `&`  operator takes the address of its argument (think of it like getting a pointer out of a variable). If you apply `&` to a pointer than you are taking a pointer out `p` which is a pointer already and this is how you end up with a pointer to pointer.

I suggest you to get a good C book and study pointers properly.